# How to connect variables to fields in a database?

Tags: database, delphi

I have a .mdb database that is connected via an ADOConnection and an ADOTable to a DBGrid in Delphi. I find it cumbersome to continuously retype: `dmPAT.ADOTable1.fieldbyname[].value;`
when doing typical database things.

Is there a way to link these fields separately to global or local variables so that I could only reference the table and then immediately the field via a variable? I remember reading about it somewhere online and I have seen mentions, though never methods on how to implement such a thing.

Comment: Google Delphi db-aware controls - they transfer data automatically between fields and on-screen controls.

Comment: @MartynA I love you

Comment: Btw, there's quite a good one at http://etutorials.org/Programming/mastering+delphi+7/Part+III+Delphi+Database-Oriented+Architectures/Chapter+13+Delphi+s+Database+Architecture/Using+Data-Aware+Controls/

Comment: You can also double click on the table component on the form and in the editor that comes up right click and select add all fields. This requires the connection/query/table be open at design time. Gives you objects to access the fields like ADOTable1Fieldname. You can also right click and select new field to create them manually but it is more work.

Comment: There are many lines of code that are cumbersome to have to type over and over. Use copy-and-paste, Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V. it speeds up coding considerably.